# How to draw line with curve using Custom Paint for graph - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-custompainter, flutter-custompaint

Im working on a designing a graph in flutter using `CustomPaint`.

[image]

I have achieved this design using `canvas.drawLine()`.

My question is how to make the sharp edges of line to curved smooth edges?.

My code with `drawline()`

```dart
List<Offset> points = const [
  Offset(0, 10),
  Offset(100, 300),
  Offset(300, 100),
  Offset(600, 500),
];

for (int i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) {
      Offset start = Offset(points[i].dx, points[i].dy);
      Offset end = Offset(points[i + 1].dx), points[i + 1].dy);

      canvas.drawLine(start, end, xPaint);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/interpolation/

Comment: How to use this in flutter Custom paint path

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is by using `path.relativeQuadraticBezierTo();`

Here is the official documentation : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path/relativeQuadraticBezierTo.html

It takes 4 parameters which are offset positions (X, Y) and then draw a curve line between those points.

Comment: How to use this?

Comment: I have studied about this and tried. I can't able to acheive.

Comment: You can create a method paint for example, and then instantiate a new Paint() (`Paint paint = Paint();`) and a new Path() (`var path = Path();`) objects inside this method. You can then directly call  `relativeQuadraticBezierTo` to the path instance : `path.relativeQuadraticBezierTo(x1, y1, x2, y2);`

Comment: That's fine. How to use this in graph.

Answer (score 1):

This pub package provides a quick way to create a smooth curve - https://pub.dev/packages/smoothie